# Make push notifications appear as pop up when app is on background with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification, react-native-firebase

I am setting up push notifications with my react native app to android users using Firebase Cloud Messaging. So far I have followed *mostly* this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@anum.amin/react-native-integrating-push-notifications-using-fcm-349fff071591). I managed to make push notifications to show on lock screen, and deal with them when the app is on foreground. When app is on background, though, I can't manage to show notification as a pop up. It appear on the notification tray, but it does not show a pop up, like gmail's or whatsapp's  notifications do.

I believe my problem is that I am not sending the correct params with the message. I am using firebase console, so it's not very flexible. How can I config (programmatically) an notification to show as pop up upon receival?

EDIT:

Setting Up notification Channel works for newer android devices - tested on Android 8.1 (API level 27).

On older devices - testing on Android 6.0 (API level 23) -, heads up notifications still doesn't appear. I am sending the following message using aws sns console:

```js
{ 
  priority: 'high',
  content_available: true,
  notification: { 
     title: 'hello',
     body: 'Just test',
     android_channel_id: 'test-channel',
     sound: 'default' 
  },
  data: { title: 'title', body: 'body', sound: 'default' }
}
```

I also sent messages using Firebase console setting Priority High and Sound Enabled, with and without Android Channel Id. None of that worked. The notification arrives silently on tray bar. This [discussion](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1297) shows the same problems, but the [solution](https://medium.com/@yangnana11/how-to-set-up-firebase-notification-in-react-native-app-android-only-4920eb875eae) one person pointed did not work for me. I didn't go through editing the react-native library code a lot. I tried section **Problems with older Android version (Foreground)**, it made heads up appear on foreground, but not on background, which is the intended behaviour here.

Furthermore, is seems that this is an unresolved issue to quite a few people using this react native package ([github issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2059), [github issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1781)).

So, I think I should reformulate my question. For Android 7.1 or lower(testing on 6.0):

1. Is setting priority='high' and notification.sound='default' supposed to be enough to show heads up notification? (From my research it should be)
2. Do I need to make any further configuration on my application code to go from notification arriving silently on tray bar to it appering as a heads up?

Comment: Are you really using GCM?  It's been deprecated.  You should be using FCM instead.  Also, the FCM documentation explains how do what you're describing.  Have you gone through that documentation?

Comment: I am using FCM indeed. I have scrambled the concepts. Thanks for your comment. I will correct it on my post.

Comment: And did you go through the FCM documentation to figure out if it tells you what you need to do?

Comment: I found this [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) that specify the message properties for FCM. I don't see any property related to show as pop up on background or not, though. I also checked by firebase and firebase-react-native docs if setup instructions matched the ones on the tutorial.

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: @ismailalaoui I’ve not had the time to test your solution yet. I’ll get back to you as soon as I do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you @ismailalaoui for contributing to this question. I wasn't able to make notifications to shows as heads up when received by System Tray, so I had to go with a work around. I will show how I did it with react-native-firebase.

For new android devices, [you should create a notification channel](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/android-channels). Add the following on your App.js

```
componentDidMount(){
  ...
  const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel('test-channel', 'Test Channel', firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max).setDescription('My apps test channel'); //add this line

  firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel); //add this line
}
```

For older devices, I had to go with a work around. Instead of using notification messages, I used data messages, so you can listen to then on the background. [See item 4](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/messaging/receiving-messages).

First create a new file bgMessaging.js:

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

export default async (message) => {
  // handle your message
  const notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
  .setNotificationId(message.messageId)
  .setTitle(message.data.title)
  .setBody(message.data.body)
  .android.setChannelId('test-channel')
  .android.setSmallIcon('ic_launcher')
  .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.Max)
  .setSound('default');

  await firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification);
  console.log({message})
  return Promise.resolve();
}
```

On your index.js file, add:

```
import bgMessaging from './src/bgMessaging'; // <-- Import the file you just created

...

AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage', () => bgMessaging);
```

react-native-firebase is using Headless JS to run the javascript code you defined in `bgMessaging`. According to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android.html) you need to add the service to AndroidManifest.xml.
On android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml add:

```
<application>
  ...
  <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService" /> <!--Add this-->
  ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

to show notification in pop up like whatsApp , you should set your notification channel importance with `IMPORTANCE_HIGH`

from the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#importance)

> Makes a sound and appears as a heads-up notification

```
int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance)
```

**Edit :**

for device running **lollipop** --> **Nougat** , you are required to set a vibrate or ringtone to make Heads-up work. However, here's a quick hack that doesn't require VIBRATE permission to produce a head-up notification . [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Heads-up)

```
notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This worked for android 8.1. For android 6.0, notifications still doesn't appear as heads up. I have edited my question, please take a look.

Comment: For future reference, [this](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/android-channels) is how notification channels are created on react native with react-native-firebase

Comment: Where am I supposed to put this code? On my client or my server? Because when receiving notification only messages on background [it goes straight to System Tray](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive). Does any part of the code interacts with the notification only message upon receipt? If you meant to include this code on server when sending the message, isn't configure sound enabled an priority high on firebase console enough to do it?

Comment: You are supposed to put this in you  notification builder on mobile side !

Comment: Can you be more specific about it? I've put your code on the notification builder that can be used while the app is running. It did nothing for the notification on background. I am not really familiar with android code. I do take a look inside and can get modifications done, but i need to know what I am looking for. I am using react-native-firebase, so its a lot of library code to be lost with.

Comment: Ah okei well , if you build notification using builder you can use the code a wrote you ! And i also add link to official doc which could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

**For react-native-firebase v6:**

To create a channel add the following lines to **MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.os.Build;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// any other code goes here
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("500", "MainChannel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationChannel.setShowBadge(true);
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Test Notifications");
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{400, 200, 400});
            //notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
}
```

This is the message sent from the server

```
const message = {
notification: {
    title: data.subject,
    body: data.message,
},
data: {
    id: data.id,
    title: data.subject,
    body: data.message,
    origin: 'chat',
    request: 'test'
},
android: {
    priority: 'high',
    notification: {
        title: data.subject,
        body: data.message,
        sound: 'default',
        priority: 'high',
        channelId: '500'
    }
},
token: "TOKEN"
};
//firebase admin
admin.messaging().send(message)
            .then((response) => {
                // Response is a message ID string.
                console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error sending message:', error);
            });
```

Found this answer on a **GitHub** issue thread. All credit goes to them.
Tested on **android Nougat(v7)** and **Pie(v9)**

Comment: How are you telling the backend about the channel `MainChannel `